# Is it possible to mix oils on an object (or weapon) to have multiple effects?

Tags: magic-items, weapons, adnd-1e

I was wondering if it was possible (or wise) to mix oils. In one game I had oil of flaming, and another oil of concussive impact. Applying the oils, one after another I applied them to my character's ammunition to create ammo (in this case arrows for a long bow). I termed "arrows of fiery impact." Despite being allowed to do it by the DM, I was wondering if RAW it would be allowed, or if there are even rules concerning this in AD&D.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is allowed. As to if it is a good idea ...

In the rules there is a [Potion Miscibility](http://greyhawkery.blogspot.com.au/2011/05/dmg-reflections-potion-miscibility.html) table which applies equally to oils. Basically if you mix potions (or oils) you roll on this table to see what happens:

> - (01) EXPLOSION! Internal damage is 6-60 h.p., those within a 5" radius take 1-10 h.p. If mixed externally, all in a 10' radius take 4-24 hit points, no save.
> - (02-03) Lethal poison results, and imbiber is dead; if externally mixed, a poison gas cloud of 10' diameter results, and all within it must save versus poison or die.
> - (04-08) Mild poison which causes nausea and loss of 1 point each of strength and dexterity for 5-20 rounds, no saving throw possible.; one potion is cancelled, the other is at half-strength and duration.
> - (09-15) Immiscible. Both potions totally destroyed, as one cancelled the other.
> - (16-25) Immiscible. One potion cancelled, but the other remains normal (random selection).
> - (26-35) Immiscible result which causes both potions to be at half normal efficacy when consumed.
> - (36-90) Miscible. Potions work normally unless their effects are contradictory, e.g. diminution and growth, which will simply cancel each other.
> - (91-99) Compatible result which causes one potion (randomly determined) to have 150% normal efficacy. (You must determine if both effect and duration are permissible, or if only the duration should be extended.)
> - (00) DISCOVERY! The admixture of the two potions has caused a special formula which will cause one of the two potions only to function, but its effects will be permanent upon the imbiber. (Note that some harmful side effects could well result from this...)

This is the sort of awesomeness that AD&D had which, sadly IMO, was pruned as being too tough on players. However, also IMO, player's stupid enough to do chemistry experiments with magical chemicals get what they deserve.

Comment: this is for potions, not oils as the results say "deadly if consumed," not what happens if applied to an object.  I don't think you'd want to internally consume an oil of fire or an oil of concussive impact!

Comment: @JesseCohoon Right, you'd be looking at the "externally mixed" results

Comment: @Weaveworker89 I'm not sure i follow. Would you mind explaining. Maybe I'm just a bit dense tonight

Comment: @JesseCohoon Oils are a subtype of potion, and use all the same rules except where differences are noted. They're just a potion (which means “magical liquid”) that goes on instead of in you.

Comment: (Pss! *3.5* has optional [potion miscibility](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/dnd/20060401b), too.)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie what I'm getting at is for results that come up poison, the deadliness of said mix, would it be deadly to the person making said mix, or enemies shot into or both?

Comment: @JesseCohoon The first (lethal) poison result would be a cloud around the mixer, the second (mild) would be a (mild) contact poison. Pretty much as it describes on the table.

Comment: @JesseCohoon could well be deadly for the object (ie. destroying it, making it less effective, lose enchantment, etc)

Comment: There's an extra problem in the OP's example. Oil of flaming seems rather likely to set other oils on fire, destroying their effects. On the good side, this might make the oil of flaming last longer.